# TI Simplelink BLE Debugging - can't place breakpoints in most of code

Tags: debugging, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments, code-composer

I'm posting this and then answering myself to document the issue for others.

I am using the TI CC2650 Launchpad with the Simplelink BLE stack. The project I compile and run is Project Zero (with edited code and additional profiles).

I want to place breakpoints in some functions inside the profile. For most of them i can't! When I look in the disassembly while debugging, I see that symbols are not available.

The only places I *can* place breakpoints are in main.c or inside callbacks.

How do I place breakpoints elsewhere? Where are my symbols?

Answer (score -1):

So the deal was this - the functions I was trying to place breakpoints in were *static* functions, internal to the C modules containing them. Out of those, most were only used once in the code. So the compiler inlined them!

So in order to achieve debugging for these functions, one has to *disable compiler optimizations*. That disables inlining, and causes the symbols for those functions to generate.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, as it uses information not given in the question. Self-answering is fine, but you have to provide all information  in the question. This could be a comment or addition to the question. Best would be to delete both.

Comment: The extra information is part of the answer.
The symptoms I, and probably others too, were seeing, are described in the question.
The answer then gives an explanation for the situation.

Comment: "The extra information is part of the answer." - That's not what anyone else  would know. Read [ask]!